# How to restrict user not to enter negitive manually for Number Type?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am having input box with number type i am restricting the min to 1
still user can able to enter manually minus,  How can i restrict.

```
<input type="number" min="1" placeholder="No.of Employees" className="m-l-15 form-control col-md-8 col-sm-8" name={el.subscription_plan_id} onChange={this.noChanges.bind(this, i)} value={el.noofemployess}></input>
```

Comment: After keeping also user can be able to enter - manually, which i got answer from duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like using absolute value (Math.abs()) will do the trick for you

```
<input type="number" min="1" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" placeholder="No.of Employees" className="m-l-15 form-control col-md-8 col-sm-8" name={el.subscription_plan_id} onChange={this.noChanges.bind(this, i)} value={el.noofemployess}></input>
```

Comment: its not working still i can able to enter -

Comment: As my value i am having dynamically based on array count so my value={el.employees} is there how i can set oninput

Comment: this.value if i am using i am not able to restrict